# Rails 3.2 Tasks in the background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, background, delayed-job

I'm running Rails 3.2 on Heroku, and I'm using **Delayed_job** to manage background tasks.

The app produces a CSV which is downloaded through the browser to the person that requested it. The file though, is HUGE, and takes up to 30 seconds to generate.

My controller looks like this:

```
def index
    @unpaginated = @search.result.order("created_at DESC")   # load all matching records

respond_to do |format|
      format.csv { render csv: @unpaginated, filename: 'outlets_' + Time.now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d") }

end
```

How would I move something like this into a background job?

Comment: There are loads of tutorials online. Try them out first. If you have a  specific problem, comeback and post it here.

Comment: You could use send_file with the delay method instead of respond_to

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

1. create a background job for the file generation.
2. redirect to a wait page that waits for the background job to complete and refreshes periodically
3. when the background job completes, redirect to a url for the file.

Optionally step 2.5 is upload the generated file to amazon s3, which makes step 3 easier.